# Binary Search only returns one statement

Tags: java, binary-search

I'm new to binary searches and I tried a program that would find the position of a value inputted by a user. My code however only seems to return a low=-1 value which leads to the program saying "the value was not found". I think I did something wrong with my binary search code, but I am not experienced with these and may have missed something? Here's my code for the binary search:

```
static public int search (int[]numbers,int target, int count)
{
    int high = numbers.length;
    int low = -1;
    int middle = (high+low)/2;
    
    while(high-low>1)
    {
        count++;
        middle = (high+low)/2;
        if(numbers[middle]>target)
        {
            high = middle;
        }
        else if(numbers[middle]<target)
        {
            low = middle;
        }
        else if(numbers[middle] == target)
        {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(numbers[middle]);
        System.out.println(middle);
    }
        if(low == -1 || numbers[low]!=target)
        {
            low=-1;
            return low;
            
        }
        else
        {
            return low;
        }
        
        
}
```

And here is part of the code which asks users for an input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    int [] numbers = new int [50000];
    int target;
    int count=0;
    
    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("randNums.txt")); 
        for(int i=0;i<50000;i++)
        {
            numbers[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }
        br.close();
        
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        
        System.out.print("Choose a number between 1-100000000 to search for: ");
        target = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        
        
        int low = search(numbers, target, count);
        if(low==-1)
        {
            System.out.println("The number was not on the list.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The number is at position " + low);
            System.out.println("It took " + count + " comparisons to find the number.");
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: [Here are some good pointers](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for debugging. Assuming that you are able to explain the purpose & expected behavior of all the code, I suggest to use a debugger tool to step through the code, statement by statement. Have you found a specific part of the code that does not work the way you expect? Which part, and what sorts of changes have you attempted to solve that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search function has some issues. The implementation of the binary search in the search function should be like this:

```
    static public int search (int[]numbers,int target, int count)
    {
        int high = numbers.length-1;
        int low = 0;
        int middle = (high+low)/2;
        
        while(high>=low)
        {
            count++;
            middle = (high+low)/2;
            if(numbers[middle]==target)
            {
                return middle;
            }
            else if(numbers[middle]<target)
            {
                low = middle+1;
            }
            else if(numbers[middle]>target)
            {
                high=middle-1;
            }
            System.out.println(numbers[middle]);
            System.out.println(middle);
        }
         return -1;
                    
    }
```